# Can I create a cycle that increment number of pages?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have to create a cycle that increment a number previously set.
This is the situation:

1. I receive a xml tag (es. pagnum) with a "start-number" of pages (es. like 1120)
2. I need to increment this number according with the number of printed pages(es. like print 60 pages?then 1120-1121-1122 ... 1280)

I imagine a cycle like : pagnum+1 --> increment pagnum of 1 unit and go on until last page.
I have no idea to do this (like in C++) on xsl language.

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
<xsl:template match="documento">
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master
            master-name="pages-normale"
            page-width="297mm"
            page-height="210mm"
            margin-top="0.5cm"
            margin-bottom="0.5cm"
            margin-left="0.5cm"
            margin-right="0.5cm">
        <fo:region-body   margin-top="2cm" extent="20cm"/>
        <fo:region-before margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="1cm" extent="7cm"/>
        <fo:region-after  margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="1cm" extent="1cm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence
        master-reference="pages-normale"
        initial-page-number="1"
        force-page-count="even"
        language="it"
        country="it">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
        <fo:block>
        <fo:table  width="100%" border-width="0.5mm" margin-bottom="4mm" border-style="transparent">
        <fo:table-column  column-width="50%"/>
        <fo:table-column  column-width="50%"/>
        <fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell border-style="normal">
                                    <fo:block font-size="15" font-style="oblique" font-weight="bold">
                                    Scipola S.r.l           
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell border-style="normal">
                                    <fo:block font-size="8" font-weight="normal" text-align="right">
                                    <xsl:template name="recursive-template">
                                       <xsl:param name="var" select="pagnum"/>
                                       <xsl:choose>
                                         <xsl:when test="$var > 0">
                                           <xsl:value-of select="$var"/>
                                           <xsl:call-template name="recursive-template">
                                             <xsl:with-param name="var" select="$var + 1"/>
                                           </xsl:call-template>
                                         </xsl:when>
                                         <xsl:otherwise/>
                                       </xsl:choose>
                                    </xsl:template>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-header>
```

Any suggestion?

I expect that the number page, shown on the right-top of the paper, start from 1120 and increment with every printed pages.

Comment: Please post a simple example of input and expected output.

Comment: Ok, done. Can you help me please?

Comment: Done?? I see neither.

Comment: Unless you are controlling pagination (that would mean you are setting page breaks and none of the content between them is longer than a page) you cannot do this. The XSLT stage would have no idea of the number of pages which takes place in the final step of XSL-FO to output format.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your code. Most obviously, `xsl:template` can only appear as a top-level element, that is, an immediate child of `xsl:stylesheet`: it can't be nested inside another `xsl:template`. The other thing that's clearly wrong is that your recursive template doesn't terminate: if called with a parameter value > 0 then it will continue calling itself indefinitely.

Apart from those details, you've roughly got the right idea - though I haven't examined your problem in enough detail to see if there might be a much simpler way of doing it.

Comment: I'm not studying this language, but I need an explanation to do this. i can't believe there isn't a simple way to to this simple things.
Of course I dont manage well the language, than I learn doing the code.
It's up to you to explain to me an easy solution, I don't need moral lesson.

Comment: Sorry, but if you're writing code in a language that you are making no effort to learn, then a moral lesson is precisely what you need. Stop wasting my time.

Comment: I want to make effort to learn, but I don't have time now to search a instruction that's not in my native language and read all the documentation to find this simple thing. However I work all the day, SORRY if I might want an ADVICE cause my brain is tired. Only for information, I dont waste time, becouse I do this for work, and work mean money.

Comment: If you engaged a plumber to work on your central heating, and he constantly made phone calls to find out how your boiler worked, saying that he couldn't find time to get proper training because "work means money", how would you react?

Comment: I'm a student, new to work, new to all.. No one pretend from me the professionality, I mighty learn, dont you believe? No one is born pre-learned. If you don't want to share, then don't answer please. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using XSL FO, if your intention is to use this as the page numbering in the document for the printed pages, then you do not need anything like you are trying to do.

You see in your template, you have `initial-page-number="1"` on the `<fo:page-sequence>`. Just set that to 1120 and not 1 and let the formatter do its job and apply page numbers. You use `<fo:page-number/>` to output the page number.

Now if you are looking for a solution where you can process this information in sequence, then FOP provides a log or likely API call or logger in which you can examine the results of the format and get the number of pages that resulted. You could use that number as input to the next cycle. I would use an `<xsl:param>` passed into the XSLT to set the next initial-page-number.

Without deeper coding into the formatter which it is running in the XSL FO to output stage, you cannot use the page-number in anyway and certainly not in the XSLT stage because unless you are controlling the whole pagination (meaning you are injecting page breaks and you are guaranteeing that content between them is shorter than a page), you have no idea what that pagination will be at XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following simplified example:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <start>1120</start>
    <amount>20</amount>
</input>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="start to xs:integer(start + amount - 1)">
            <page n="{position()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </page>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <page n="1">1120</page>
   <page n="2">1121</page>
   <page n="3">1122</page>
   <page n="4">1123</page>
   <page n="5">1124</page>
   <page n="6">1125</page>
   <page n="7">1126</page>
   <page n="8">1127</page>
   <page n="9">1128</page>
   <page n="10">1129</page>
   <page n="11">1130</page>
   <page n="12">1131</page>
   <page n="13">1132</page>
   <page n="14">1133</page>
   <page n="15">1134</page>
   <page n="16">1135</page>
   <page n="17">1136</page>
   <page n="18">1137</page>
   <page n="19">1138</page>
   <page n="20">1139</page>
</output>
```

Comment: Because this is XSL FO, I wonder if the OP is actually thinking that this is the page numbers that would result from the format and not a simple counter. I am adding an answer in case this is what this are looking for.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a cicle that start from a number, gave me from a tag, like <startpage>980</startpage>, that print the page number one: 980, number two: 981, number three:982 excetera..

Comment: Then why is your question tagged `xslt-2.0` ?